# Como crear archivos distintos a partir de un dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe con una decena de columnas. Tres de ellas son: "username" y "producto_adquirido" y "unidades". El dataframe refleja las compras de usuarios en una tienda online.

```
 Username     producto_adquirido     unidades
 pedro        camiseta               3
 juan         tejanos                2
 sara         chaqueta               1
 pedro        chaqueta               1
 juan         tejanos                3
 sara         camiseta               2
```

¿Qué necesito? Me gustaría poder disponer de una función para su reutilización que permita crear dataframes fácilmente exportables que contengan la información agrupada. El proceso sería más complejo que con 3 columnas (debería hacerlo con 6, por lo menos), pero si domino el proceso con tres creo que no tendré problemas en aplicarlo a "gran escala".

Los outputs deberían consistir en distintos dataframes, uno para cada username y para cada producto, recogiendo las compras, el sumatorio

Pongo un ejemplo de output:

```
df_pedro_producto_1:

producto_adquirido     unidades
camiseta               3
```

Siguiente DF

```
df_pedro_producto_2:

producto_adquirido     unidades
chaqueta               1
```

Siguiente DF (nótese que en el caso de Juan, el producto adquirido es siempre el mismo, de modo que bastará con 1 DF que contenga las 2 compras:

```
df_Juan_producto_1:

producto_adquirido    unidades
tejanos               2
tejanos               3
```

Y así, todo de forma automática. Un dataframe que contenga, para cada username, todas las compras realizadas del mismo producto, con las unidades en cada compra.

Es algo muy tedioso, pero tengo la sensación de que la solución parte de algo muy simple. Creo, vaya.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te propongo una solución sencilla a algo que es tedioso, (seguro que hay muchas más) y te explico detalladamente lo que estoy haciendo:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

df_compras = pd.DataFrame({"username": ["Pedro", "Juan", "Sara", "Pedro", "Juan", "Sara"],
             "producto_adquirido":["camiseta", "tejanos", "chaqueta", "chaqueta", "tejanos", "camiseta"],
             "unidades":[3,2,1,1,3,2]})


usuarios = list(set(df_compras.username.to_list()))
productos = list(set(df_compras.producto_adquirido.to_list()))


claves_usuario_producto = list(product(usuarios, productos))

dataframes_usuario_producto = {}
for clave1, clave2 in claves_usuario_producto:
    df_creado = df_compras[(df_compras["username"] == clave1) & (df_compras["producto_adquirido"] == clave2)]
    if len(df_creado) > 0:
        df_usuario_temp = {clave2:df_creado}
        dataframes_usuario_producto[clave1] = df_usuario_temp
```

## Explicación del código

### Parte 1: limpiar duplicados.

```
usuarios = list(set(df_compras.username.to_list()))
productos = list(set(df_compras.producto_adquirido.to_list()))
```

Aquí lo que hago es obtener los valores únicos de las columnas por las que quieres buscar y guardar los `DataFrame`.

1. Primero los saco del `DataFrame` con el método `.to_list()` esto nos da una lista.
2. En la lista anterior, tengo que limpiar los repetidos, para no iterar por el mismo nombre y el mismo producto varias veces, por lo que utilizo `set()` para limpiar duplicados.
3. Después como lo que quiero es iterar, tengo que volver a **convertirlo a una lista** ya que un `set()` no es un iterable. Por lo que utilizo `list()`

### Parte 2: obtener distintas combinaciones.

```
producto_cartesiano = list(product(usuarios, productos))
```

Para esto usamos del módulo `itertools` la función `product()`, esta nos devuelve un generador que es el [producto cartesiano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producto_cartesiano) de las dos listas. Es decir todas las combinaciones de usuarios y productos posibles. Si quieres saber más sobre `itertools` aquí te dejo [su documentación](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

Como nos devuelve un generador, **necesitamos convertirlo a un iterable** por lo que le aplicamos `list()`

### Parte 3: Almacenar los distintos DataFrames

Aquí ya puedes **almacenarlos como tu consideres correcto**, en una lista, guardarlos directamente, o en un diccionario que es lo que he elegido yo. Te quedo cada punto explicado, asignado en el código

```
dataframes_usuario_producto = {} #Punto 1
for clave1, clave2 in claves_usuario_producto: #Punto 2
    df_creado = df_compras[(df_compras["username"] == clave1) & (df_compras["producto_adquirido"] == clave2)] #Punto 3
    if len(df_creado) > 0: #Punto 4
        df_usuario_temp = {clave2:df_creado} #Punto 5
        dataframes_usuario_producto[clave1] = df_usuario_temp #Punto 5
```

Vamos por partes:

1. Me creo un diccionario vacio, **que va a ser un diccionario de diccionarios** en el que voy a ir almacenando el DataFrame de cada usuario con el correspondiente producto.
2. Itero por cada clave que tenemos distinta de usuarios y productos
3. Selecciono cada usuario con cada respectivo producto
4. Despues uso `if` porque habrá usuarios que no habrán commprado un determinado producto y por tanto el DataFrame estará vacio.
5. Por último me creo un diccionario temporal para cada usuario cuya clave será el producto y el valor, el `DataFrame` que hemos filtrado en el punto 3. Y después, asigno dicho diccionario como valor a la clave que será el usuario.

Una vez tenemos esto, ya tenemos cada usuario con su producto y podemos hacer lo que queramos:

```
dataframes_usuario_producto["Sara"]["chaqueta"]
```

**Salida:**

```
username producto_adquirido  unidades
2     Sara           chaqueta         1
```

Lo bueno de tenerlo en un diccionario, es que puedes acceder a ellos y hacer distintas operaciones. Pero como te dije al principio, puedes guardarlo directamente, usar una lista, etc.

Comment: Oh, genial! Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda y por una respuesta tan excelente!

Comment: De nada siempre es un gusto ayudar :) Si te ha servido mis respuesta, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es aceptando la respuesta en el tick  "aceptar respuesta",  y ¿Por qué no? ¡Darle también un voto positivo! Esto no solo me recomenpensara a mí por la ayuda, si no que hará que la pregunta perdure en el tiempo y le pueda ser de ayuda a personas con el mismo problema que tú en el futuro! Te recomiendo leer [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia)

Answer (score 0):

excelente la respuesta de arriba, lo único que quería aportar es que hay una forma un poco mas optima de extraer los usuarios y productos únicos del dataframe.

```
usuarios = df_compras.username.unique()
productos = df_compras.producto_adquirido.unique()
```